# list index out of range in python

Tags: python, excel

```
import glob
import xlrd

from xlwt import Workbook

wb = Workbook()

for file_name in glob.glob("foo*.xls"):
    wb_orig = xlrd.open_workbook(file_name)
    for ws_orig in wb_orig.sheets():
        ws = wb.add_sheet('{0} {1}'.format(file_name, ws_orig.name))
        for rx in range(ws_orig.nrows):
            for cx in range(ws_orig.ncols):
                ws.write(rx, cx, ws_orig.cell_value(rx,cx))

wb.save("mefoo.xls")
```

i tried the above code in many ways to merge multiple excel sheets into one workbook........
this code gives error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\my python\Internship\mergestackoverflow.py", line 16, in <module>
    wb.save("mefoo.xls")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 634, in save
    doc.save(filename, self.get_biff_data())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 615, in get_biff_data
    self.__worksheets[self.__active_sheet].selected = True
IndexError: list index out of range
```

please help me to solve the error..

Answer (score 8):

The only way that you can get that IndexError is if there are no sheets in the output workbook.

You need to examine your `glob.glob("foo*.xls")`; it looks like it's returning no files.

Comment: @Cold-Blooded: Please consider "accepting" the answer (big tick to the left)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to not use an absolute path in the glob.

```
for file_name in glob.glob("C://your//full//path//here//foo*.xls"):
  #population/merging code here

wb.save("mefoo.xls")
```

As to why this solved the problem, I do not know.  But I hope this helps somebody.