# List Index out of Range (Tripped up Newbie)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newbie programmer and I'm trying to cross over from beginner to intermediate level but sometimes I have issues troubleshooting and finding my error(s). Here is the problem I'm working on. I'm coding a sudoku puzzle and the first step is to make sure it's a perfect square or matrix. So like 3 x 3 or 9 x 9. In my code below, you'll see that I'm getting the count for the rows then the count for the columns. If those count are equal, then it's a perfect square.

```
def check_square(square):
    # Count Row
    i = 0
    j = 0
    countRow = 0
    countCol = 0

    while square[i][j] <= len(square):
        print("This is i:", i, "This is j:",j)
        countRow = countRow + 1
        j = j + 1
        if j == len(square):
            print(countRow)
            break

    i = 0
    j = 0
    while square[i][j] <= len(square):
        print("This is i:", i, "This is j:", j)
        countCol = countCol + 1
        i = i + 1
        if i == len(square):
            print(countCol)
            break

    if countRow == countCol:
        print("True")
        return True
    else:
        print("False")
        return False
```

When I pass in a perfect square like so:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 4, 1, 3],
 [3, 1, 4, 2],
 [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

My code passes and prints out "True". But when I pass an imperfect square like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
[2, 4, 1],
[3, 1, 4],
[4, 3, 2]]
```

My code fails and gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jim/PycharmProjects/Sudoku/sudoku.py", line 113, in <module>
    [4, 3, 2]])
  File "/Users/jim/PycharmProjects/Sudoku/sudoku.py", line 84, in check_square
    while square[i][j] < len(square):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I stepped through my code and discovered that it's failing on this line:

```
while square[i][j] <= len(square):
```

For example, if I have a square with a length of 4 and only 3 items in my row when j = 2 and j increments by 1 it throws the error because it's expecting more entries. I get really tripped up by these errors and it's really frustrating because I don't know how to fix them quite yet. Any help would be great.

** EDIT **
My problem is different because I'm checking an imperfect square.

Comment: Stop running off the end of the array, and you won't have that error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list index out of range in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308022/list-index-out-of-range-in-python)

Comment: At the bottom of the loop, print `i` and `j` - this should give you an idea of what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `square` is not a square, but is instead a rectangle, then you have two lengths to deal with:  (a) The number of rows, i.e. `len(square)`, and (b) The number of columns, i.e. `len(square[0])`.

In your first loop, `j` runs through the rows, i.e. from 0..3 in your example.  But it is being used as a column index, even though the valid column indices only run from 0..2.  So instead of checking for `j == len(square)`, instead check if `j == len(square[0])`.

Comment: Thank you! It says that I can accept your answer in 8 minutes. How did you figure this out so fast? I'm so slow with programming.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Basically I just looked at the index variables, and checked their ranges to see where they could exceed the corresponding dimension.